# A story about liars

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Evelyn, Skylar, Alayna, Madelyn, Jonathon, Lara, Alyin, Felix, Iris, Bob and Roslina live on an island where some people always tell the truth, and the rest always lie.

- Roslina says "*Alyin and Evelyn lie*"
- Roslina says "*Skylar would say 'Either Alayna lies, or At least one of Felix or Lara is truthful*'"
- Jonathon says "*Evelyn and Skylar lie, and also Alayna is truthful*"
- Roslina says "*Either at least one of Iris or Lara lies, or Bob is truthful*"
- Felix says "*At least one of Bob or Alayna lies*"
- Iris says "*Alayna and Felix lie, and also Evelyn is truthful*"
- Felix says "*Jonathon is truthful*"
- Madelyn says "*Jonathon, Bob and Roslina lie*"

Can you figure out who are the liars and who are the truth-tellers?

[Adapted from [this crazy generator I found.](http://www.dr-mikes-math-games-for-kids.com/truth-lies-logic-puzzle-generator.html)]

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "always lie" in this context?  Does it mean that every clause is a lie or just that the statement as a whole is?  In other words does "True is True and False is True" count as "sometimes telling the truth" since the first clause is true or "always lying" since the statement as a whole is false?

Comment: @Barker The complete statement made by a liar would be false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's call everyone by their initial, except that since there are two As we'll use N for Alyin and A for Alayna. Then the answer is

> A,B,L,R,S tell the truth; E,F,I,J,M,N lie

Derivation:

> *Begin*
>
> ```
> R = ~N & ~E
> R = (S = (~A | (F|L)))
> J = ~E & ~S & A
> R = ~I | ~L | B
> F = ~A | ~B
> I = ~A & ~F & E
> F = J
> M = ~B & ~J & ~R
> ```
>
> *Eliminate J (=F)*
>
> ```
> R = ~N & ~E
> R = (S = (~A | (F|L)))
> F = ~E & ~S & A
> R = ~I | ~L | B
> F = ~A | ~B
> I = ~A & ~F & E
> M = ~B & ~F & ~R
> ```
>
> *Eliminate F (=~A|~B)*
>
> ```
> R = ~N & ~E
> R = (S = (~A|~B|L))
> ~A|~B = ~E & ~S & A
> R = ~I | ~L | B
> I = ~A & A & B & E
> M = ~B & A & B & ~R
> ```
>
> *Eliminate I (=false) and M (=false, not actually used elsewhere)*
>
> ```
> R = ~N & ~E
> R = (S = (~A|~B|L))
> ~A|~B = ~E & ~S & A
> R = true | ~L | B
> ```
>
> *Eliminate R (=true)*
>
> ```
> ~N & ~E
> S = (~A|~B|L)
> ~A|~B = ~E & ~S & A
> ```
>
> *Eliminate N (=false) and E (=false)*
>
> ```
> S = (~A|~B|L)
> ~A|~B = ~S & A
> ```
>
> *Note that if ~A then LHS of second of those is true, hence RHS is, hence A, contradiction*
>  *Eliminate A (=true)*
>
> ```
> S = (~B|L)
> ~B = ~S
> ```
>
> *Eliminate B (=S)*
>
> ```
> S = (~S|L)
> ```
>
> *Note that if ~S then RHS is true so LHS is so S is, contradiction*
>  *Eliminate S (=true)*
>
> ```
> false|L
> ```
>
> *Conclude that L is true*

If you want to check my work, put the following into a Python interpreter and verify that you get a bunch of `True`s out (I do):

> ```
> a,b,l,r,s = True,True,True,True,True; e,f,i,j,m,n = False,False,False,False,False,False
> r == ((not n) and (not e))
> r == (s == ((not a) or f or l))
> j == ((not e) and (not s) and a)
> r == ((not i) or (not l) or b)
> f == ((not b) or (not a))
> i == ((not a) and (not f) and e)
> f == j
> m == ((not j) and (not b) and (not r))
> ```

Comment: Well that would make sense, considering it's a story about **L**iars ;)

Comment: Well, maybe it would but in fact on checking it appears to be very wrong so I goofed somewhere.

Comment: oh, wait, I think maybe I just mistranscribed something

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how you came to your conclusion (like, why eliminate this as opposed to that?) but I trust your answer is correct because you are a moderator xD

Comment: Bleh. Being a moderator is no guarantee of anything. You could trust it because I'm a mathematician and that would make more sense but still be crazy. I make a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Welp, there is a reason *why* you are a moderator; and there might be users who look up to you as one, too :) ....but let's not get off-topic here, because as they say, comments aren't for discussions. Nice answer, I will upvote once my voting limit is over :P

Comment: Who is represented by the "N"?

Comment: Alyin, as it says in the first line of the answer.

Comment: Rot13: Ebfyvan fnlf "Rvgure ng yrnfg bar bs Vevf be Ynen yvrf, be Obo vf gehgushy" naq vs Ebfyvan = G, naq O = G, gura gur "be" fhttrfgf gung arvgure Vevf abe Ynen Yvrf, znxvat gurz obgu G naq ohfgvat vg.

Comment: That may be how "or" is often used in everyday conversation, but in this sort of context it doesn't carry that implication.

Comment: Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Typed this up on my phone, hoping I didn't end up being too slow haha.

My answer is:

> Truth tellers are Rosalina, Bob, Alayna, Skylar, & Lara
>  Liars are Alyin, Evelyn, Iris, Madelyn, Jonathon, & Felix

My reasoning is below. Names are shortened to first letters, except Alyin is AN and Alayna is AA. Truth tellers are labeled with a T and liars with an X.

> Assume R is a T. Then Clue #1 states that AN and E are both X.
>  Thus Clue #6 is untrue, given E is not a T. Thus I is an X.
>  Thus Clue #8 is untrue, given R is not an X. Thus M is an X.
>  Consider Clue #2. R is a T, thus if S is an X it would require AA to be a T, and for F and L to both be X. But then Clue #7 would require J to be an X. However, this would contradict Clue #3 which would be true in this scenario. Thus we have a contradiction, and S must be a T.
>  Thus Clue #3 is untrue, given S is a T. Thus J is an X.
>  Thus Clue #7 is untrue, given J is an X. Thus F is an X.
>  Thus Clue #5 is untrue, given F is an X. Thus B and AA are T.
>  Finally, given S is a T, one element of Clue #2 must be true. To avoid contradictions, the sole option is that L is a T.

The above satisfies all 8 clues. Also, if we took our initial assumption to be

> R is an X then upon inspection Clue #4 would make B an X & I and L both T, and then Clue #6 would make E a T & AA and F both X. However Clue #5 would be a true statement, thus F cannot be an X, and so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

> If we assume Felix = T then
>  Jonathon = T
>  Evelyn = L
>  Skylar = L
>  Alayna = T
>  Iris = L
>  Madelyn = L
>  Bob = T
>  Roslina = T and if Bob = T then Iris and Lara both are T, but Iris = L
>  Therefore Felix is a LIAR.

Therefore:

> Felix = Liar
>  Jonathon = Liar
>  Evelyn = Truth
>  Skylar = Truth
>  Alayna = Liar
>  Iris = Truth (claims Alayna is a liar)
>  Madelyn = Truth (claims Jonathan is a liar)
>  Bob = Liar
>  Roslina = Liar
>  Lara = Liar
>  Which leaves Alyin, whom I missed before, and = Truth

Comment: Updated to include a person I missed before

Comment: Undeleted this post as it at least gives an answer for each person based on "logic". I do, however, believe that logic based on the parameters creates an impossibility.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found an issue in my original post and instead of changing everything I'm reposting..

First, some logic:

Let's assume Felix is Truthful (T)

> If Felix = T then
>  Jonathon = T which means
>  Evelyn = L and
>  Skylar = L and
>  Alayna = T, and since Iris says Alayna = L
>  Iris = L, which makes..
>  Evelyn = L, and since Madelyn claims Jonathon is L..
>  Madelyn = L, which makes..
>  Bob = T and

BUT...

> Felix says at least one of Bob or Alayna is L, but in the above they are both T proving Felix a LIAR!!

This is the same result I keep getting time and again.. but this time:

> Felix = L
>  Jonathon = L
>  Evelyn = T
>  Skylar = T
>  Alayna = L
>  Iris = T
>  Evelyn = T
>  Madelyn = T
>  Bob = L ... *But wait!! Felix says at least one of Bob or Alayna are Liars, which is now TRUE.. but he's a proven Liar! Something is up..*

What if this riddle isn't about what it says it's about?

> Bob (B), Lara (L), Alayna (A), Madelyn (M), Evelyn (E), and Skyler (S).. Blames? Has kind of a negative connotation to it.
>  Could be these be the Liars?
>  Felix (F), Alyin (A), Iris (I), Roslina (R). Wait... Fair? Sounds positive..
>  Could these be the truthful ones?

> I do realize that Alayna and Alyin can be interchanged.. but the point of the puzzle remains the same that their names spell out Blames and Fair.

It's out of the box thinking, but it seems to me that the logic above proves that no combination can fit 100%.

Comment: When you start by supposing F is a liar, how do you infer that E tells the truth? My guess: you reckon that if a liar says "X and Y and Z" you're allowed to infer that X, Y, and Z are all false, but I don't think that's what's intended: all you know is that _at least one_ of X,Y,Z is false.

Comment: Because the beginning states: some people *always* tell the truth, and the rest *always* lie. So if A is a liar and they say B is also a liar, B has to be truthful.

Comment: But if they say B and C are _both_ also liars, then it suffices for _either_ B _or_ C to be truthful, because either way A will have lied.

Comment: (The usual convention in these puzzles is that each _complete statement_ a "liar" makes is false.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan "Roslina says "Alyin and Evelyn lie" & Roslina says "Either at least one of Iris or Lara lies, or Bob is truthful" I take these as two separate statements, both of which would need to be reversed due to Roslina being a Liar. Are you suggesting only one of the two statements needs to be false, or are you saying that only one side of the "Either at least one of Iris or Lara lies, or Bob is truthful" needs to be false?

Comment: I am saying that each of those two statements should be treated separately, so that if R is a liar each must be false and if R is a truthteller each must be true; but that the individual bits of which they are made could go either way so long as each of those whole statements comes out true/false as appropriate.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan In the statement "Either at least one of Iris or Lara lies, or Bob is truthful" the only ways to make that a lie are to say that Iris and Lara are liars but Bob is truthful, or Iris and Lara are truthful and Bob is a liar. If at any point Iris, Lara, and Bob are all liars or all truthful then the statement becomes a truth. This is reflected in my answer.

Comment: If R is a liar then it must be that I and L are truthful and B is a liar. The first of your two "only ways" won't do it. I think you're interpreting "this or that" to mean "either this or that, _but not both_" and I do not believe that is the intention in this puzzle.

Comment: I stand by the idea that there is only one way ", or" should be interpreted. The sentence begins with "Either," which means the entire sentence is one statement and that statement requires the two clauses to be evaluated as they relate to one another. IMO, the logic is flawed.

Answer (score -1):

So let’s start with Alayna, she’s a

> Lie, this is because, according to the rule given in the link in the question, states that “If A says “A would say X” you know that X is true whether or not A is a liar” as Skylar say she’s a lie,

We can say Skylar & Evelyn

> are a truth-tellers

Roslina & Jonathon

> are liars, Jonathon mention Evelyn & Skylar are a lie, Roslina mention a lie too with saying Evelyn is a lie

Iris

> is a truth-teller, 2/3 person that she mentioned which is Alayna & Evelyn are correct, so we pick

Felix

> as a lie, we may use Felix’s statement on Jonathon for this too

Madelyn

> also saying the truth by 2/3 person mentioned by her makes

Bob

> a lie

Iris & Lara

> truth-tellers by using Skylar only statement we can say Roslina lie about her statement on Iris & Lara

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect.  The important fact about the "A says 'A would say X'" is that the person making the statement is the same person is being talked about.  In other words the statement is about something the person talking would say.  In this case Roslina is talking about what Skylar would say so the statement is "A says 'B would say X'". For the rule to apply it would need to say "Roslina says 'Roslina would say X'".

Comment: No it’s like Alayna says “Alyin would say ’Felix is...’”

Comment: Look at the explanation on the site again.  The logic only works because the speaker and the person who "would say" something are the same person.  That is why it says "**A** says '**A** would say X'", **A** refers to the same person both times.  That is why the site says it is rare to see a clue like that.  In your example Alayna and Alyin are two different people so they would be **A** and **B** with the 'Felix is...' being **X**.